# Meteor use React Router with Iron Router

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'd like to know how to use React Router with Iron Router. The reason is that I started using React and React Router for an existing project.

Here is what I am doing currently:

- Render a Blaze template using iron router
- Using `Template#onRendered`, render React app inside the template.

**routes.js**

```
Router.route('/admin/:tab1?/:tab2?/:tab3?/:tab4?', function () {
  this.layout('admin');
});
```

**admin.html**

```
<template name="admin">
  <div id="admin-wrapper"></div>
</template>
```

**admin.js**

```
Template.admin.onRendered(function () {
  render((
    <Router>
      ...
    </Router>
  ), this.find('#admin-wrapper'));
});
```

But the problem is that the React app does not redraw the components as the URL changes. I have to refresh the whole page in my browser to see an updated page. Any ideas, or alternative approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two routers are incompatible because they push different states to `window.history`.

A solution is to use `memoryHistory` to configure routes in React Router. Then, listen to `window.history.pushState` and push the new url to `memoryHistory`.